# GitLab runner registration

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner

By using helm GitLab runner registration is successful on the Kubernetes cluster, but on the GitLab server, it is not displayed. Got an error that no runner registered.

I tried to register GitLab runner on the Kubernetes cluster by using helm and it registered successfully. But on the GitLab portal, the runner is not visible.